# If statement does not react

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on a school project. I am to make a simulation of the german Enigma machine.

I want the array to be "round", as if the index is beyond the array length, it shall continue from the array start again.

I don't see how the following should not work. If the `wh0pos` becomes more than the array length, which is 10, it should subtract 10.

```
If (wh0pos > wheel1.Length) Then ' Hvis 
    wh0pos = wh0pos - wheel1.Length
End If
If (0 > wh0pos) Then
    wh0pos = wh0pos + wheel1.Length
End If

wh1 = wh0 + wheel1(wh0pos) ' Bogstav-værdi + værdiens position i rotor 1
```

Our teacher does not know what can possibly be wrong, so I hope someone from here can help me out. Full code is below.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim wheel1(0 To 25), wheel2(0 To 25), wheel3(0 To 25) ' Her definerer jeg de tre rotorer
    Dim whPos1, whPos2, whPos3 As Integer ' Her definerer jeg de tre rotorers position

    Dim wh0 = 0
    Dim wh1 = 0
    Dim wh2 = 0

    Dim charGoBack As Integer

    Dim wh0pos As Integer
    Dim wh1pos As Integer

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        wheel1 = {3, 2, 1, -2, -3, 3, 2, 1, -2, -3} ' Første array (indeholder forskydningen i tal)
        wheel2 = {+1, -1, +2, +1, -3, 3, 2, 1, -2, -3} ' Andet array

        whPos1 = 5 ' Sætter rotor1 position til 0
        whPos2 = 0 ' Sætter rotor2 position til 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        whPos1 = whPos1 + 1 ' Hver klik, flyttes rotor-position 1 gang

        If (whPos1 = 25) Then ' Hvis rotor1 er nået sidste bogstav
            whPos1 = 0 ' Sæt rotor1 til 0
            whPos2 = whPos2 + 1 ' Flyt rotor2 én gang
        End If

        wh0pos = wh0 + whPos1 ' Tager process1 og adderer rotorflytningen

        wh0 = (Asc(TextBox1.Text) - 65) ' Konverterer bogstav til ASCII-værdi



        If (wh0pos > wheel1.Length) Then ' Hvis 
            wh0pos = wh0pos - wheel1.Length
        End If
        If (0 > wh0pos) Then
            wh0pos = wh0pos + wheel1.Length
        End If

        wh1 = wh0 + wheel1(wh0pos) ' Bogstav-værdi + værdiens position i rotor 1

        wh1pos = wh1 + whPos2

        If (wh1pos > (wheel2.Length - 1)) Then ' Hvis 
            wh1pos = wh1pos - wheel2.Length
        End If
        If (wh1pos < 0) Then
            wh1pos = wh1pos + wheel2.Length
        End If
        wh2 = wh1 + wheel2(wh1pos) ' Udkom af rotor1 + værdiens position i rotor 2


        Label1.Text = wh0
        Label2.Text = wh1
        Label3.Text = wh2
        charGoBack = (wh2) + 65 ' Tager den krypterede ASCII-værdi og gør klar til at omkonvertere til bogstav igen

        If (charGoBack > (65 + 26)) Then ' Hvis charGoBack er større end ASCII-intervallet for bogstaver
            charGoBack = charGoBack - 65 ' Subtraher resultat med 65
        End If

        If (charGoBack < 0) Then ' Hvis 0 er større end charGoBack
            charGoBack = charGoBack + 65 ' Adder det med 65, så vi kommer op i ASCII-bogstavrækken
        End If



        Label4.Text = Chr(charGoBack) ' Printer krypterede tekst
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I didn't get much into detail, but did you try to execute step by step? Does it enter your if statement at all? Besides, I think you can get rid of if completely, and just use `Mod`: `wh0pos = ((wh0pos - 1) Mod wheel1.Length) + 1`

Comment: I am not sure if it enters the if-statement at all, no. The wh0pos will eventually become larger than 10, and then the program crashes, saying it couldn't find index 10 of the array. Will look at the `Mod`.

Comment: The code that guards `wh0pos` is not quite equal to the guard code for `wh1pos`. Maybe split that out into a function? (input whpos and wheellength, output the new whpos)

Comment: So the error is not on wh0pos, but wh1pos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am incredibly stupid, and I have found out why it crashes.

The array hasn't got 26 positions, and the program tries to find a letter that hasn't got a position.

Said with other words, if the program wants to output T, it has the program value of 19. The if-statement says if it's higher than 9, it should subtract 9. It is now 19 and it makes the result 10.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comments that it crashes when the index is equal to 10. The reason for that might be that in your arrays the last element's index is 9 but the length of the array is 10 (counting starts from 0). That might be the reason why it crushes i.e. the program is trying to access a[10] but it is out of bounds.

Comment: I tried
`If (wh0pos > (wheel1.Length - 1)) Then ' Hvis 
    wh0pos = wh0pos - wheel1.Length
End If`
aswell. It didn't work either. The program tries to index array position 10 no matter what.